# Create a custom symbolic link to a library at install time with CMake

Tags: unix, build, cmake, symlink

Under Linux with CMake, I'm building a shared library libIex-2_0.so.10.0.1

```
ADD_LIBRARY (Iex SHARED
  [*.cpp]
)
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(Iex PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME "Iex-2_0")
```

The 10.0.1 version is set with a call to

```
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES ( Iex
  PROPERTIES
  VERSION 10.0.1
  SOVERSION 10
)
```

In the installation folder, these links are created

```
libIex-2_0.so -> libIex-2_0.so.10
libIex-2_0.so.10 -> libIex-2_0.so.10.0.1
libIex-2_0.so.10.0.1
```

However, to match previous builds made with another build system, I need to add a legacy symbolic link, stripping the 2_0 suffix :

```
libIex.so -> libIex-2_0.so.10.0.1
```

What would be the proper CMake way to create such a link ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One way to do it could be using CMake [`add_custom_command`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#command:add_custom_command) and [add_custom_target](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#command:add_custom_target). In your case it would be something like the following:

```
 SET( legacy_link   ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/libIex.so)
 SET( legacy_target ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/libIex-2_0.so.10.0.1)
 ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND( OUTPUT ${legacy_link}
                     COMMAND ln -s ${legacy_target} ${legacy_link}
                     DEPENDS install ${legacy_target} 
                     COMMENT "Generating legacy symbolic link")

 ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET( install_legacy DEPENDS ${legacy_link} )
```

At this point you should have a target `install_legacy` in your generated Makefile with the correct dependency to generate `libIex.so`.

Comment: While the code in this answer looks simpler than in the [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52322753/3440745), using `add_custom_target` for **install** is not a good idea and generally should be avoided in preference to  proper `install()` command flow.

Answer (score 5):

Another way is to run some `install(CODE shell-script)`. It does correctly attach to the general "make install" target by the way. With better control on the working_directory it is also possible to create relative symlinks easily.

I did also require that `make install DESTDIR=/buildroot` works and for that it is required to leave $DESTDIR unexpanded until the shell-script is invoked. Along with some magic for portability it looks like this:

```
get_target_property(libname MyLib OUTPUT_NAME)
get_target_property(libversion MyLib VERSION)
set(lib ${CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_PREFIX})
set(dll ${CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_SUFFIX})
install(CODE "execute_process(
    COMMAND bash -c \"set -e
    cd $DESTDIR/${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    echo -n .. Installing: `pwd`
    ln -sv ${lib}${libname}${dll}.${libversion} ${lib}${libname}${dll}.11
    echo -n .. Installing: `pwd`
    ln -sv ${lib}${libname}${dll}.${libversion} ${lib}${libname}${dll}.12
    \")")
```

P.S. assuming `include ( GNUInstallDirs )` here.

Comment: "shell-script" is a *misleading argument name* fo `install(CODE)` command flow. It is actually a **CMake script**, or, more precisely, a **CMake code** (for a *CMake script* there is `install(SCRIPT)` command flow).