# CMake creating symlinks after install for specific files

Tags: cmake, installation

Currently having the problem that some specific config files should be in a folder and some of these config files need to have a symlink to somewhere else. (Legacy code and not allowed to change the directory structure or logic)

My idea was the following code:

```
set(SRC_LIST 
    ex1.cfg
)

set(TARGET_LIST 
    ex1_with_fancy_name.cfg
)

while(${SRC_LIST} AND ${TARGET_LIST})
    list(GET ${SRC_LIST} 0 SRC)
    list(GET ${TARGET_LIST} 0 TARGET)

    ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND( 
        OUTPUT ${TARGET}
        COMMAND ln -s ${SRC} ${TARGET}
        DEPENDS ${TARGET} 
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/some_folder
    )

    ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(
        link_${TARGET} 
        DEPENDS ${TARGET} 
    )

    list(REMOVE_AT ${SRC_LIST} 0)
    list(REMOVE_AT ${TARGET_LIST} 0)
endwhile(${SRC_LIST} AND ${TARGET_LIST})
```

Problem is that these custom targets nor commands won't be executed if  I start `make install`.

Bonus question: Does `make install -j` speed up the instllation process as it does with `make`?

Got the idea to try this from here: [Create a custom symbolic link to a library at install time with CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18706942/create-a-custom-symbolic-link-to-a-library-at-install-time-with-cmake)

Comment: `make install` implicitly performs `make all`. You need to add `ALL` keyword to `add_custom_target` for build it by default (with `make`) and by `make install`. Actually, I would suggest to follow [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52322753/3440745) in the referenced question for additional install steps: `add_custom_target` is good for **building** steps, but it badly cooperates with a project's **installation**.

Comment: As for bonus question, in CMake area `make install` implicitly performs `make all`, but otherwise it is **sequential**. That is, `make install -j` would have similar performance as `make -j` (parallel) followed by `make install` (non-parallel).

Comment: Thanks for the advise. still the install scripts in the while loop are not executed. I wrote everything now by hand with `install(CODE execute_process())` and it works.

Comment: I have marked you question as a duplicate for the referenced one. This mark neither implies low-quality of the your question nor prevents your question from receiving upvotes. "Duplicate" prevents only to answer your question: it should be an answer post to the original question, so all possible solutions for a single problem will be collected in a single place.